# How can I aggregate fields based on the value of another field?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have an Azure hosted application in which some of our users have been complaining of difficulty logging-in. So I added some logs which show up in Application Insights. A sample of the data is shown below:

[image: Log results]

I need to create a report that shows:

- The number of unique users (the `Identifier` field) that successfully logged-in and the number of unique users that failed to login.
- The number of failed login attempts that preceded a successful attempt (if any) - is this even possible in KQL?

One one my attempts was:

```
customEvents
| order by timestamp asc
| summarize TotalUserCount=dcount(tostring(customDimensions["Identifier"])),
            SuccessCount=countif(name startswith "Success"),
            FailureCount=countif(name !startswith "Success")
```

But this is wrong, I need `countif(name...)` to also be distinct by `Identifier`.

I'm new to KQL and so would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Following SO guidelines, please remove the image and supply the data sample in text format / as datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from analyzing the data in the session level.
It's very easy to take it from there and summarize it to the user level etc.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
// Setup
let p_event_num                     = 30;
let p_identifiers_num               = 3;
let p_max_distance_between_events   = 2h;
let p_names                         = dynamic(["Unsuccessful login. Invalid cred", "Unsuccessful login. Account wa", "Successful login"]);
// Internal
let p_identifiers   =   toscalar(range i from 1 to p_identifiers_num step 1 | summarize make_list(new_guid()));
let p_names_num     =   array_length(p_names);
let customEvents    =   materialize
                        (
                            range i from 1 to p_event_num step 1 
                            |   extend  ['timestamp [UTC]'] = ago(24h*rand())
                            |   extend  Identifier          = tostring(p_identifiers[toint(rand(p_identifiers_num))])
                            |   extend  name                = p_names[toint(rand(p_names_num))]
                        );
// Solution starts here
customEvents
|   project-rename ts = ['timestamp [UTC]']
|   partition hint.strategy=native by Identifier
    (
            order by    ts asc
        |   extend      session_id          = row_cumsum(iff(ts - prev(ts) >= p_max_distance_between_events, 1, 0))
        |   summarize   session_start       = min(ts)
                       ,session_end         = max(ts)
                       ,session_duration    = 0s
                       ,session_events      = count()                        
                       ,session_successes   = countif(name  startswith "Successful")
                       ,session_failures    = countif(name !startswith "Successful")
                       ,arg_max(ts, name)
                        by Identifier, session_id
    )
|   project-away    ts
|   project-rename  session_last_name = name    
|   extend          session_duration = session_end - session_start
|   order by        Identifier asc, session_id asc   
|   as              user_sessions
```

| Identifier | session_id | session_start | session_end | session_duration | session_events | session_successes | session_failures | session_last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 0 | 2022-06-26T20:22:22.4006737Z | 2022-06-26T20:22:22.4006737Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 1 | 2022-06-26T22:47:01.8487347Z | 2022-06-26T22:47:01.8487347Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Successful login |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 2 | 2022-06-27T04:57:15.6405722Z | 2022-06-27T07:32:10.4409854Z | 02:34:54.8004132 | 4 | 1 | 3 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 3 | 2022-06-27T10:44:19.8739205Z | 2022-06-27T12:46:14.2586725Z | 02:01:54.3847520 | 3 | 0 | 3 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 4 | 2022-06-27T14:50:35.3882433Z | 2022-06-27T14:50:35.3882433Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 3b169e06-52e5-45d8-b951-62d5e8ab385b | 5 | 2022-06-27T18:33:51.4464796Z | 2022-06-27T18:47:06.0628481Z | 00:13:14.6163685 | 2 | 0 | 2 | Unsuccessful login. Invalid cred |
| 63ce6481-818e-4f3b-913e-88a1b76ac423 | 0 | 2022-06-26T19:27:05.1220534Z | 2022-06-26T20:24:53.5616443Z | 00:57:48.4395909 | 2 | 0 | 2 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 63ce6481-818e-4f3b-913e-88a1b76ac423 | 1 | 2022-06-27T02:17:03.4123257Z | 2022-06-27T02:36:50.1918116Z | 00:19:46.7794859 | 3 | 1 | 2 | Successful login |
| 63ce6481-818e-4f3b-913e-88a1b76ac423 | 2 | 2022-06-27T13:27:27.2550722Z | 2022-06-27T14:32:39.6361479Z | 01:05:12.3810757 | 3 | 2 | 1 | Successful login |
| 63ce6481-818e-4f3b-913e-88a1b76ac423 | 3 | 2022-06-27T17:20:34.3725797Z | 2022-06-27T17:20:34.3725797Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 6ed81ab3-447e-481d-8bb3-a5f4087234bb | 0 | 2022-06-26T22:38:39.3105749Z | 2022-06-26T22:38:39.3105749Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 6ed81ab3-447e-481d-8bb3-a5f4087234bb | 1 | 2022-06-27T03:06:04.340965Z | 2022-06-27T04:49:37.3314224Z | 01:43:32.9904574 | 3 | 3 | 0 | Successful login |
| 6ed81ab3-447e-481d-8bb3-a5f4087234bb | 2 | 2022-06-27T07:11:47.260913Z | 2022-06-27T07:11:47.260913Z | 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Unsuccessful login. Account wa |
| 6ed81ab3-447e-481d-8bb3-a5f4087234bb | 3 | 2022-06-27T11:39:02.356791Z | 2022-06-27T16:49:23.5818891Z | 05:10:21.2250981 | 4 | 2 | 2 | Unsuccessful login. Invalid cred |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VVTW/aQBC9I/EfplyyrkhI0t4iKlVtD7n0kuaEkDWxx/a29i7aDwhRfnxnbWMMMRFZCYlk38ybefNmmc3gJzoEi9WqJMhJkUEntbqC39rBCo0DnYErCKwufbgZj2YzeCDnV%20NRSYyJaU3KxcpXMHTm8OX6bgeVKUNlJsnYgQCGdsgKn%20NUWocqofiJ3IZINUy2Rt4WHVRhRXaQu0mabhkhE7GYPCrrk4SszXwJpc4l93mv1ljKFBJD6WQKg5jvSaK9crDBgHg4up8so7talXvlyCgsB7qtCwFw2iZYohEGVU4gITO6ghv%20/4A41tGK717B%20qpCI18IKvxHccmyCEWbOPcyFVEUHSrRCRsI0RjcxiWp3BWiBezwibdOV792mtb4CrkFyYK80Hh0SlJx%20iqcod72Hmm7ej/FK3/o2ZFKARYXTnLVji0Ki8c/P5YXSy4Vcy1uvxafmSxocH66%2007lvkd4MM5IlYuDMSyclsqJmuPNfKJo%20QHaoPzx/Xw3skOeborMcJqg9dxDu5asKy%20rhYIMT64/2vEo1LEy%20i8l7tJQXQkj50PKtmBOJeusBdd1xdKwLfLtXPHbsCZ42vZUbCo8soQ2KevLOD5MhTbZ3/dVCcfyLjEVy9tXxuhNnPiKrS9klglOcsk90Jq/RfBt/v4LMYWbKVz3XRFI92u0J61V60grqUL%20k6JPd2Fd8U0YPp8XlvrmdW3Cru0ZRN12hoj6FRLRiaDTO9Wla582svt0MhONNxsDbaQr%20k/c5Iy2MpSlN2ThbdZPH8%20KJo8bRaf11ryzZAdGnPac1IREh9bHDbaGHFyJLrxE6%20ol5GZ2a9tE9G0bzpu5zqHvkMtDmzU5%20qsRTu894jXpNxH%207qjx6BfOWzJxi7X/Aa9E%20Z3HBwAA)

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

> *I need countif(name...) to also be distinct by Identifier.*

If I understood your intention correctly, you could use `dcountif`().

For example:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend Identifier = tostring(customDimensions["Identifier"])
| summarize TotalUserCount = dcount(Identifier),
            SuccessCount = dcountif(Identifier, name startswith "Success"),
            FailureCount = dcountif(Identifier, name !startswith "Success")
```

> *The number of failed login attempts that preceded a successful attempt (if any) - is this even possible in KQL?*

You could try using the `scan` operator for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a `dcountif`, or even about `scan`. I'll give that a try and mark your answer if it works.